# Deprecated code works safely on all Android versions and devices?

Tags: android, deprecated, deprecation-warning

I am working on a huge android project with tons of classes. Until now we are compiling with Android 3.2 and giving support to Android 2.3.

Now I am testing to compile with Android 5.1.1, but still giving support to Android 2.3. My surprise was that a lot of code is deprecated now... (`getWith(), getDrawable(), setBackgroundDrawable(), HttpRequest, ActivityGroup`, etc...). Those deprecated functions does not give compile error, but it gives deprecated warning.

I know that I can duplicate code and make special calls to deprecated methods if SDK_INT is lower than XX and calls to new methods if SDK_INT is newer than XX, but this is a huge patch, that will need a lot of duplicate code in a lot of functions in a ton of classes and packages, so, if it is possible, we prefeer to wait until we don't need to give support to oldest versions of android. It means to continue using deprecated methods until for example we only need to give support from 4.4, that will means munch less duplicated code and functions will be needed.

**The question is:** If i compile with Android 5.1.1 but still use those deprecated functions, this huge project will continue to work on all devices (from 2.3 to 5.1.1)? Now it's working compiling with Android 3.2.

I understand that Deprecated means that they are likely to be removed in a future version of the platform and so you should begin looking at replacing their use in your code, but if it is still supported and does not give a compile error, it will work well as until now. It is what I understand of deprecation. **It is right?**

Thanks.

Comment: the short answer is *NO*.   The longer one is *Some code does, some does not*

Comment: if it does not give compile error why it should not work?

Comment: I understand that Deprecated means that they are likely to be removed in a future version of the platform and so you should begin looking at replacing their use in your code but if it is still supported and does not gives a compile error, it will work perfect. It is what i understand of deprecation. It is right? –

Comment: @DerGol...lum https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html Do not mystify. How is 2.2 alive and 2.3 dead?

Comment: Sorry, misread **2.3.x (with x > 2)** is still alive too. API **9** is **dead**. Android **2.2** is still perfectly **alive**

Comment: @DerGol...lum: What's with all the bold?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Just **to emphatize** the **meaningful** words.

Answer (score 1):

Deprecated means two things:

1. There is another (maybe better) solution
2. It isn't fully support anymore

That means that your code `could` be run fine. But Google/Android don't guarantee that.

According to [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/predefined.html) the `@Deprecated` annotation says:

> @Deprecated annotation indicates that the marked element is deprecated and **should no longer be used**. The compiler generates a warning whenever a program uses a method, class, or field with the @Deprecated annotation. [...]

So please stop using deprecated methods. :)

Have you looked or do you know that there are [support-libraries](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) to help you with backward compatibility?

Comment: I dont understand what you did from google documentation. I understand that should no longer be used but if it does not give compile error why it should not work?

Comment: I understand that Deprecated means that they are likely to be removed in a future version of the platform and so you should begin looking at replacing their use in your code but if it is still supported and does not gives a compile error, it will work perfect. It is what i understand of deprecation. It is right?

Comment: The methods are there on newer platforms (so it does not give you compile time error) but they may contain only exceptions such as "Deprecated. Use *XXX* instead." They are not guaranteed to work, don't use them in production unless for compatibility reasons e.g. `setBackgroundDrawable` when `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16` and `setBackground` otherwise. That's safe.

Comment: About this, Eugen Pechanec, hey may contain only exceptions such as "Deprecated. Use XXX instead." WHere i can read that information from official source?

Comment: Depcreacted means not "We have erased this method!". It means only "don't use it". Get the information from the documentation. For example: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDrawable(int)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should work fine. But you really should use the latest methods instead of deprecated ones and use support libraries to make it compatible to the previous versions. 
All the deprecated methods that I have used have worked fine, but Google does not guarantee that they will.

Answer (score 0):

You can continue using deprecated methods, they should still work as intended. But you have to be careful, because they could be removed in future versions.

As mentioned in the documention over [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Deprecated)

> A program element annotated @Deprecated is one that programmers are
>   discouraged from using, typically because it is dangerous, or because
>   a better alternative exists. Compilers warn when a deprecated program
>   element is used or overridden in non-deprecated code.

Answer (score 0):

It may stop working with new version.

Example: LocationManager.addNmeaListener(GpsStatus.NmeaListener listener)

Deprecated from API 24.

Stop Working in API 29 (Android 10). No implementation inside (returns false).

In documentation: No-op method to keep backward-compatibility.

Had trouble to find why old code stop working.