# Deprecated gradle features

Tags: android, dependencies, deprecation-warning

Hey i have a question about deprecated features builds. Can theese make it impossible to run your app on a simulator? I have some of theese in my code and i cannot run the app on my simulator anymore.

I have no clue how to fix it i tried to update the versions of the newly added libraries i had in my gradle file and i still cant get the app to run on my simulator why is this?

the only thing i can find on the web about it is that it shouldn't be that big of a trouble but im not sure if that is correct? Here is my gradle implementations. this is the error im getting.

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See  https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'

    def nav_version = "2.3.5"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"
}
```

i have checked theese websites

[Deprecated code works safely on all Android versions and devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31469681/deprecated-code-works-safely-on-all-android-versions-and-devices)

https://www.quora.com/How-can-resolve-problem-of-deprecated-method-in-android-studio

what im doing when i got this error was following a tutorial within firebase MVVM project making and adding the libraries for Navigation graph. This is the tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FuAz-ahdk0E&t=601s

Comment: When asking help with an error, always try to provide the error on the console or logcat so it´s easier to figure out what could be happening

Comment: i cant get an error in logcat because i cant eaven run the app in the emulator. when i click run i can run the project but only without the app on the emulator it just says success

Comment: And it just says not applicable for project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deprecated in most programming context does not mean that you should forcefully update to the new implementation no matter what it takes. It basically says: The team/programmer that´s maintaining this will no longer be making changes or additions to this method, so if some error comes up in the future it will probably not be addressed and you could do nothing about it. Normally they provide a new way of achieving what you want and, if possible, you should migrate your code; but that does not mean that the old code will just stop working.

So, the short answer would be, using deprecated build features should let you compile correctly, the error is not on that direction.